# Angularjs uib-accordion-heading not open when we add <i> tag

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I have `<uib-accordion-heading>`, functionality I require is, 
When click on the header should open its child and trigger `ui-sref`. I found online solution is to add `<i>` tag which satisfies both my requirements but now, When I click on `<i>` tag image that is ">" then it opens its child and also triggers `ui-sref`, but user need it's child to be open when just click on header text too. 
below code,

```
 <uib-accordion-heading ng-model="checkTitle"  >
                                        <span ui-sref="formName" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">{{ names.name }}</span>
                                         <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}" ></i>
                                    </uib-accordion-heading>
```

Comment: The are both inline elements, try adding `<i>` inside `<span>`

Comment: '`<uib-accordion-heading ng-model="checkTitle"  >
                                            <span ui-sref="formName" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">{{ names.name }}
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}" ></i></span>
                                        </uib-accordion-heading>
          `
 tried this but not working. :(

Comment: Perhaps it's will be much more helphul to understand, if you will provide a jsfiddle